# Efficient way to fill default values for multiple columns on Big size dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, default-value

I have a dataframe `obs` of size 1.5 million records. I would like to fill in NA's with default values as shown below.

```
obs = pd.DataFrame({'person_id' :[1,2,3],'obs_date':['12/31/2007','11/25/2009',np.nan],
       'hero_id':[2,4,np.nan],'date2':['12/31/2017',np.nan,'10/06/2015'],
       'heroine_id':[1,np.nan,5],'date3':['12/31/2027','11/25/2029',np.nan],
       'bud_source_value':[1250000,250000,np.nan],
       'prod__source_value':[10000,20000,np.nan]})
```

The logic is to fill 3 default values based on column name.

1)  cols ending with `id` - fillna with `0`

2)  cols ending with `value` - fillna with ' ' (blank/empty)

3)  cols containing `date` - fillna with `12/31/2000`

Though my code below works fine (based on SO suggestion), Is there anyway to fasten it?

```
%%timeit
c = obs.columns.str
c1 = c.endswith('id')
c2 = c.endswith('value')
c3 = c.contains('date')

obs_final = np.select([c1,c2,c3], [obs.fillna(0), obs.fillna(''), 
obs.fillna("12/31/2000")])
obs_final = pd.DataFrame(obs_final, columns=obs.columns)
```

It takes `19.5 s ± 303 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` - Is this normal?

Is there anyway to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select columns with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and use `fillna`:

```
obs.loc[:, c1] = obs.loc[:, c1].fillna(0)
obs.loc[:, c2] = obs.loc[:, c2].fillna('')
obs.loc[:, c3] = obs.loc[:, c3].fillna("12/31/2000")
```

Comment: It took `872 ms ± 4.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`.Will mark as solution

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is going to make it faster, but you could try it

```
obs[obs.columns[c1]] = obs[obs.columns[c1]].fillna(0)
obs[obs.columns[c2]] = obs[obs.columns[c2]].fillna('')
obs[obs.columns[c3]] = obs[obs.columns[c3]].fillna("12/31/2000")
```

Comment: It throws an error as `ValueError: Item wrong length 18 instead of 1067948.
`

Comment: Yes my bad, I'll fix it, i thouts c1, c2, c3 were lists of column names